# Javascript loading scripts (masonry, pirobox) troubes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, video

I have a problem with running javascript.

On my website: http://s479828935.onlinehome.fr/work.php when you open the page and all videos are not yet posted, my pirobox js does not work. Only once all the videos are loaded and I click on a video, the video opens well in a modal window. But it's long...

How can I do, if you click on a video without all the videos are loaded, it opens in a modal window (pirobox script) and not in a full window? I tested including the js early, at the end, but nothing succeeds.

Otherwise it's the same for the left menu, when you go to the artist page and then to work page it closes once the entire page is loaded (and again it depends on the browser sometimes never close), whereas it should close directly when clicking the link. And I include js menu before masonry and pirobox ...
Calls JS files are visible with firebug.

Thank you in advance for your help.